# Should you upscale images for mobile using CSS or a photo editing tool?

Tags: css, image, mobile, photoshop

I want all images for a mobile site to be 640px wide, based on iPhone screen size.
All images should be the full width of the screen when shown `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }`.

For the images that are smaller than 640px wide, is it better to use the above CSS to scale them up, or should I use Photoshop or something to scale the actual image up?  Does it even make a difference?

So does scaling up an image using CSS result in a better or worse image quality than using something like Photoshop to increase the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling images up doesn't go well for the quality of said images, you need to sort out your priorities on this one. You can work on those images and increase the quality and size of those images in Photoshop so you don't lose any quality when resizing, but this will increase page loads or you could lose some quality, but improve page loads with smaller but more crappy images.

Comment: Cheers.  I opted to work with them in photoshop and work on the output quality to come to a sort of 'compromise'.

Comment: Good choice, nowadays we have faster internet connections so don't worry about your images affecting your websites page load too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to target each device (computer vs mobile) perfectly you can use javascript to switch out the images. This can be done really easily using http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html or similar libraries.

If the images are graphics or icons I might suggest just making them svgs and using those instead as they are crisp at a greater range of resolutions. If you go with this option its best to make their sizes multiples of two.

Comment: I was reading about that, looks interesting.  This is a dedicate mobile site so no need to target each device.  Most images are photographs, and the only graphic I have I don't have access to the SVG / original unfortunately.

Comment: Oh okay, if you're targeting specifically then I would say make your images 640 from the get go! :-)